# how to save the pdf file in our local project directory using nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm doing fileupload using angularjs. After chosen file should be save in our local project directory named like 'uploads'. Please if you know tell me how to do.

Comment: You can use npm module to save file on server. First please share your code to help.

Comment: Please share what you have done so far...

Comment: HTML:<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="myFileField">Select a file: </label>
                    <input type="file" demo-file-model="myFile" class="form-control" id="myFileField" />
                </div>
                <button ng-click="uploadFile()" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

> pdfController.js

```js
    var myApp = angular.module('filedownload', ['ngFileUpload']);

myApp.controller('fileCtrl', function ($scope, fileUploadService, $http) {


    $scope.uploadFile = function () {
        console.log('file modal');
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
            $scope.base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;

            var dataObj = {
                "pdf": $scope.base64
            }

            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
            $http.post('http://localhost:3001/upload', dataObj, config)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('Success response: ', response);
            }, function (response) {
                console.log('Error response: ',response);
            });
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        
        myApp.service('fileUploadService', function ($http, $q) {

    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
        console.log('file in service: ', file);
        console.log('uploadUrl in service: ', uploadUrl);
        //FormData, object of key/value pair for form fields and values
        var fileFormData = new FormData();
        fileFormData.append('file', file);


        var deffered = $q.defer();
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fileFormData, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', 'Accept': 'application/pdf' }

        }).then(function (success) {
            console.log('Success: ', success);
            deffered.resolve(success);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
            deffered.resolve(error);
        })

        return deffered.promise;
    }
});

/*
A directive to enable two way binding of file field
*/
myApp.directive('demoFileModel', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', //the directive can be used as an attribute only

        /*
         link is a function that defines functionality of directive
         scope: scope associated with the element
         element: element on which this directive used
         attrs: key value pair of element attributes
         */
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.demoFileModel),
                modelSetter = model.assign; //define a setter for demoFileModel

            //Bind change event on the element
            element.bind('change', function () {
                //Call apply on scope, it checks for value changes and reflect them on UI
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    //set the model value
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> HTML:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="myFileField">Select a file: </label>
                    <input type="file" demo-file-model="myFile" class="form-control" id="myFileField" />
                </div>
                <button ng-click="uploadFile()" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```